# PowerBI how to change total in table to average

Tags: powerbi

I have a table on powerBI that automatically generates a row of totals at the bottom. This is irrelavent to my data, and was wondering if there's a way to have a row of averages instead?
Refer to image - I want the last row (which automatically appears) to be average not total

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its already showing average I guess.

Comment: yeah but i want the bottom row to be averages of every column ie average of the averages, average of the maximum, etc etc

Comment: Can you provide small amount of sample data with expected output from them. And also the calculation logic.

Comment: You need to write your own measure if you want averages over specific granularities other than the rows of the data table (since the total row is ignorant of what granularity is displaying in the table).